# How to iterate on unordered pairs inside an unordered_set?

Tags: c++, unordered-set

What's a concise way to iterate on unordered-pairs of elements in `unordered_set`?

(So order doesn't matter and elements should be different)

> e.g. {1, 2, 3} => (1, 2) (2, 3) (1, 3)

My initial attempts were something like

```
for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
  for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But that's not super-convenient with iterators.

Comment: @arainone Possible case of 'I didn't read the question'.

Comment: So for some set `X` you want `{(x1,x2) | x1,x2 ∈ X, x1  ≠ x2}`? Did I read that right?

Comment: Should the overlap(`[0,1],[1,2][2,3]...`) or do you want `[0,1],[2,3][4,5]...`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Seems overlap is desired.

Comment: So you want all combinations of size `2` of the `std::unordered_set`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work, given an `std::unordered_set` `s`:

```
auto set_end = s.end();
for (auto ai = s.begin(); ai != set_end; ++ai) {
    for (auto bi = std::next(ai); bi != set_end; ++bi) {
        // *ai, *bi
    }
}
```

This is basically the iterator equivalent of the following in integers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
        // i, j
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest `std::for_each` over an old-fashioned `for` loop.

Comment: @caps `std::for_each` does not give iterators, and the inner loop depends on the iterator of the outer loop.

Comment: Just as a matter of curiosity, is there a reason you used `set_end` instead of `s.end()` in the loops?

Comment: @caps, there is **nothing** old-fashoned with `for` loop. In fact, it is `for_each` which is old fashined!

Comment: @erip Efficiency, `end()` may or may not be repeatedly computed depending on your compiler.

Comment: @erip Your edit is unnecessary, less performant, and possibly incorrect depending on overloading/type. To see why, mentally do the integer version :)

Comment: @SergeyA `std::for_each` implicitly does the `set_end` capture optimization that orlp implemented, and it does it more cleanly. However, orlp is correct about the iterators not being passed through, so he could only do `std::for_each` on the inner loop.

Comment: @caps, it is moot to compare iterator-aware loop (which uses iterators like in provided example) with for_each, since for_each doesn't allow iterator access. However, range based for loop is much better than for_each.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes. :) Range-based for is marginally better than `std::for_each`. It is almost the same thing. However, you can't use range-based for in this case without building a custom range. You could do conveniently with `boost::make_range` or somesuch, but it's the same (or less) boilerplate to just use `std::for_each`.

Comment: just for my curiosity could we early-stop the first loop one before the end? how would one do that?

Comment: @Uri We can't because `std::set` iterators are `ForwardIterator`s, which can not be decremented.

Answer (score 1):

Here is orlp's solution in semi-generic form.

```
template<typename ForwardIterator, typename DestItr>
auto cartesian_product(ForwardIterator b, ForwardIterator e, DestItr d) -> DestItr {
    using std::next;
    using std::for_each;
    for (; b != e; ++b) {
        for_each(next(b), e, [&](auto right){
            *d++ = std::make_tuple(*b, right);
        });
    }
    return d;
}

template<typename ForwardRange, typename DestItr>
auto cartesian_product(ForwardRange r, DestItr d) -> DestItr {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    return cartesian_product(begin(r), end(r), d);
}
```

[Live on Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8342f9f9f546fadc)

You could, of course, make it more generic by having overloads for custom functors to use instead of `make_tuple` and the assignment operator. The standard library algorithms tend to do so. Were I writing this for a library, I'd probably do so as well.

Comment: Don't name this `cartesian_product`, because this is definitely __not__ the cartesian product. It's the 2-combinations of a set with itself.

Comment: Hmm. Something like... `self_combination`? `self_permutations_combination`?